# How I can make a recursiv search in ad with a User whether this is in a group or subgroup?

Tags: c#, asp.net, recursion, active-directory, active-directory-group

Hi I use the Active Directory and C# in a ASP.NET Application and I want that I get a bool if a User is in a Group or in this SubGroups. I have write a method that get me whether th user is in the group but not in this Subgroups :(

How I can make a recursiv search in my method:

here my code:

```
public static bool IsUserInGroup(string dc, string User, string group) 
        {
            PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, dc);

            GroupPrincipal p = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, group);

            UserPrincipal u = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, User);

            bool isMember = u.IsMemberOf(p); 

            return isMember; 
        }

static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string dc = "company.com";
            string user = "test.w";

            bool isadmin = IsUserInGroup(dc, user, "TAdmin");
            bool isUser = IsUserInGroup(dc, user, "TUser");

            Console.WriteLine("Admin: " + isadmin);
            Console.WriteLine("User: " + isUser);

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of `IsMemberOf` method you should use `GetMembers(Boolean)` with 'true'. It will return all the members of the group - even nested. Then make a loop to check if your user principle is in the result. Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339975.aspx) link.

Additional note: try such code

```
public static bool IsUserInGroup(string dc, string User, string group) 
{
    bool found = false;

    PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, dc);
    GroupPrincipal p = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, group);
    UserPrincipal u = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, User);

    found = p.GetMembers(true).Contains(u);

    p.Dispose();
    u.Dispose();

    return found; 
}
```

Comment: yes it is the right way but I need a method that give me a bool back whether the User is in this or in the subgroups...

Comment: this method need 3 second but is this that what i need