# Get members of group nested in another group

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm developing an intranet which shows specific links only if a user is member of certain groups in Active Directory.

I'm using this code to effectively check if a user is member of a group. Works fine if the group contains users only, but it doesn't work if there's a group nested in it. What I need is to make it works even if a particular user is in the nested group!

```
public bool isMember(string user, string group)
{
    string value = "";
    bool isMember = false;

    try
    {
        DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(domain);
        DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
        mySearcher.Filter = "sAMAccountname=" + user;

        SearchResult mySearchResult;

        mySearchResult = mySearcher.FindOne();

        PropertyValueCollection prop = mySearchResult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["memberOf"];

        for (int i = 0; i < prop.Count; i++)
        {
            value = prop[i].ToString();

            string[] groups = value.Split(',');
            foreach (string property in groups)
            {
                if (groups[1] == group)
                {
                    isMember = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        entry.Close();
        return isMember;
    }
    catch (COMException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

**EDIT :**

I've found this code, which allows me to find a user, even if a nested group. The problem is that it works only if my organizational unit contains ONE group, doesn't work if there are more than one...do you think I can edit it a bit to make it work properly??

```
public bool isMember(string user, string group)
{
    bool found = false;

    PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain");
    GroupPrincipal p = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.Name, group);
    UserPrincipal u = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, user);

    found = p.GetMembers(true).Contains(u);

    p.Dispose();
    u.Dispose();

    return found;
}
```

Got this code from ->[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14332964/how-i-can-make-a-recursiv-search-in-ad-with-a-user-whether-this-is-in-a-group-or)<-

Answer (score 0):

You might consider asking AD for their token instead with `tokenGroups`. Have a look at http://dunnry.com/blog/EnumeratingTokenGroupsTokenGroupsInNET.aspx for a sample.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this.

1. Recursively check memberOf property for each group found.  Note that there can be circular references so you'll have to keep a track of groups visited to avoid infinite recursion.
2. Use the [LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475(v=vs.85).aspx) rule to search for all groups a user belongs to, directly or indirectly.  To do this you need to first get the user's DN, then search for groups that contain that userDN as a direct or indirect member.  The filter looks something like:

   ```
   String.Format("(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={0})", userDN)
   ```

IIRC option 1 is generally faster, but of course needs more code.

Comment: I would like to follow your first option, but I don't have any idea how to do it..can you help me a bit? Sorry I'm totally new to this..

Comment: I'll try to dig out a sample.  Meanwhile, you might consider as an alternative using WindowsTokenRoleProvider, with which you can use HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole to check for group membership: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.windowstokenroleprovider(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Sarah, The first time you call your IsMember method, I would save the list of groups returned by GetMembers.  Then each subsequent call to IsMember looks up in this saved collection.  By doing this you avoid repeated access to AD.

Comment: I can't access my organizational units, my second method only works with groups.. @Joe